# Emailing the data extract to users

Tags: marketing-cloud, data

Is it possible to email the Marketing Cloud data extract to the users instead of using FTP or have it sent directly to salesforce to access in reports?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach files to an email from the SFTP share using the [**AttachFile()**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/attachfile.htm) AMPScript function -- as long as you know the exact file name and the file resides in the Import directory.

There's a per attachment fee to consider.  You'll need to get those details from your SFMC Rep.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you so much for your response. What about sending all those details back to Salesforce directly so that i can access them through reports? Is that possible? Some of the information in Marketing Cloud specific info such as send id etc.